# How to Emulate Com Ports on Windows and provide VendorId and ProductId

Tags: windows, serial-port, emulation, device-driver

I need to emulate a few USB devices on Windows to write and test code without any hardware dependencies.

We use COM port emulators (here com0com) to create COM port pairs. Most devices we test by sending control signals from a controller application to any open ports which can then be picked up by device simulator applications that can return relevant commands (by way of HTTP requests). The applications are written in Nestjs (Node) and utilize the SerialPort library.

However, for some devices we need to get the specific VendorId and ProductId and I am not sure if and how this can be emulated, even if we would write our own drivers. It seems that this information has to come from the devices themselves (firmware)?

I am relatively new to software development and surely to this specific domain and I would be grateful for some directions and pointers. I am willing to invest some time to solve this, e.g. get into driver development, if I have an idea about how it could look and where to start (if at all).

Comment: USB Serial controloer chip Evaluation kits/boards sold by vendors can customize VID/PID/SerialNumber. There is also an SDK for creating the corresponding device driver. It's probably better to look for such an existing solution than to consider making them possible with software.

Comment: Thanks @kunif, that's of course an option! I would like to understand how much effort it would be to build a software only solution and if it's feasible in the first place. Any idea where to look/ start?

Comment: I'm not sure, but around Windows 7, there must have been an SDK/WDK for a framework that simulates PnP devices as an optional package. However, it seems that Windows 8 no longer supports it. You may want to look for such a thing.

Comment: OK, I'll try to do a bit more research in that direction. Thanks again!